# Visual Studio Crashes with TypeScriptDebugEngine System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, typescript

We are using Typescript 0.8.1.0, and we have run into a situation where Visual Studio crashes while debugging in Internet Explorer.  It happens as soon as we load a page with javascript.  This is the error:

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 11.0.51106.1
  Problem Signature 03: 5098c6d7
  Problem Signature 04: TypeScriptDebugEngine
  Problem Signature 05: 0.8.1.0
  Problem Signature 06: 50a1a534
  Problem Signature 07: 2c
  Problem Signature 08: 11a
  Problem Signature 09: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 405e
  Additional Information 2: 405e61bb034bc989d1c165b6e791ea8b
  Additional Information 3: 40a4
  Additional Information 4: 40a44cd3ba2d99a4ae774300b848d2cc
```

Here are the versions of the components we are running

```
Internet Explorer version: 10.0.9200.16384.
Visual Studio: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012, Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1
Typescript: 0.8.1.0
```

I have tried running this with all other extensions disabled but to no avail.  We were not experiencing this issue with 0.8.0.0.  I thought that it may have something to do with source maps, but we have not generated any and we are not using the source maps switch.  We are able to debug the application in Chrome without any issues.

Outside of this information, I am at a loss for what else to add.  If you guys can point me in the right direction for things to check, I will update this question with my response.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Received this same behavior and found the TypeScript Debug Engine didn't like .map files other than the ones created for TypeScript files using tsc --sourcemap switch and will crash VS.

**Resolved this by** removing .map files generated for non-TypeScript files that were loaded on the same page as compiled TypeScript .js files.

In my case, I was using the Web Essentials plug-in for right-click minification which also generates a related .map file. I deleted the minified .map files and VS no longer crashed.  Note: A .map file is also generated for bundles using the Web Essentials plug-in.

Comment: Ah, excellent.  That solved my problem.  So even though I had disabled Web Essentials, the map files it created still existed in the path.  I deleted them, and it works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Typescript 0.8.1.0 has few known crashes.. Typescript 0.8.1.1 has fixed these issues.

Comment: No, it hasn't.  The problem still exists in 0.8.1.1.  The above solution fixed it.